# how to melt only selected columns (integer and string) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have this dataframe:

```
no   id    type   xa   xa    01   02
1    bar    any   2    3     1     3
2    foo    all   3    4     0     1
```

the columns I need to transform is coming after the `type` column, and I actually have plenty of them coming after the `type` column and the column type is in the form of string and also integer.

so I need to transform any column coming after `type` to be in dedicated columns which are `category` and `values`, and the expected result will be as follow:

```
no   id   type   category   values
1    bar  any      xa          2
1    bar  any      xa          3
1    bar  any      xa          1
1    bar  any      xa          3
2    foo  all      01          3
2    foo  all      01          4
2    foo  all      01          0
2    foo  all      01          1
```

I probably can use df.melt, but I am still not sure on how to use it in my case.

How do I suppose to write my script so that I can get my desired dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `df.melt`:

```
>>> df = df.melt(['no','id','type'], var_name='category', value_name='values')
   no   id type category values
0   1  bar  any       xa      2
1   2  foo  all       xa      3
2   1  bar  any       xa      3
3   2  foo  all       xa      4
4   1  bar  any       01      1
5   2  foo  all       01      0
6   1  bar  any       02      3
7   2  foo  all       02      1
>>>
```

Comment: @jezrael Ah! I community wiki